# Is Xbox Live required to play Minecraft on Xbox 360?

Tags: xbox-360, xbox-network, minecraft-legacy-console

My son has an Xbox 360 and wants to play Minecraft but the salesperson said he need to have Xbox live (issued in the country where he is) before he can play. Anyone please enlighten me about this?

Answer (score 10):

If you want to play online, you need to have a [Xbox Live Gold](http://www.xbox.com/en-US/live/gold) account, which is a paid subscription.

If not, the normal [Xbox live (silver)](http://xbox.about.com/od/xbox360faqs/f/xblsilverfaq.htm) account (which is free) is enough to play singleplayer.

Comment: May be worth mentioning that you can play locally with friends on a free account (e.g. 2 controllers plugged into the same xbox).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need Xbox Live to play offline. If he wants to play with friends, then you need to get Xbox live Gold.

I hope this helped.